# BrightScript Eclipse Plugin Not Showing Up After Install on OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, brightscript

After installing the BrightScript Eclipse Plugin for Roku development it acted like it installed fine but is not visible anywhere in Eclipse. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I figured this out although I wasted a good part of two days trying to uninstall and reinstall the plugin on various eclipse versions. If you look here:
http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Eclipse+Plugin+Guide

and look at the release notes for the 9/30/2013 release you'll see that it says the plugin is disabled if not running Java 1.7 or higher. I believe eclipse for mac ships with a version of Java but it must be older than this. I went here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

and downloaded the latest version and there it was. Hope this saves someone else some time.